# Variations of the problem of the number of ways to divide $N$ items into $K$ bins

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

I can use the stars and bars approach to solve the problem of dividing $N$ items into $K$ distinct bins with no restrict on the number of items each bin has to have. It's simply
$$
\binom{N+K - 1}{K - 1} 
$$

Essentially $N+K-1$ is the number of items plus the number of "bars," where the latter is the number of bins minus 1. The binomial coefficient essentially says "For $N+K-1$ things, we want to choose $K-1$ things and have these be the bars, and the remaining things be the $N$ items." Alternatively, it could also mean "For $N+K-1$ things, we want to choose $N$ of these things and have these be the items, and the remaining things will be the $K-1$ bars."

What if there's a constraint on how many items each bin has? For example, what if we constrained each bin to have at least 1 item (assume $N \geq K$)? What would be the approach? I was thinking in that situation, we can just remove $K$ items from $N$, leaving us with $N-K$ items, then we just simply apply the stars and bars approach again but with $N-K$ items instead of $N$, so we get

$$
\binom{N - 1}{K - 1}
$$

As long as we have sufficient number of items, we can generalize this to a minimum of $c$ items in each bin
$$
\binom{N - (c - 1)K - 1}{K - 1}
$$

But how do we handle the case where there's a different minimum amount for each of the bins? For example, what if we specify that only 1 of the bin has to be non-empty, i.e., only 1 of the bin has to have at least 1 item?

In this situation, I think you can remove 1 item, place this item in, say, bin 1, and then use the formula
$$
\binom{N - 1 + K - 1}{K - 1}
$$
to place the remaining $N - 1$ items. However, this only accounts for bin 1 being non-empty, but there are $K$ possible choices for the non-empty bin, so the answer is

$$
K \binom{N - 1 + K - 1}{K - 1}
$$

So for this case, it wasn't that difficult. But I would like to generalize this to be able to handle some minimum requirement for all bins. i.e.,, bin i must have at least $a_i$ items, where
$$
\sum_{i=1}^K a_i \leq K \\
a_i \geq 0
$$

Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: First off, your understanding mostly seems correct.  I haven't perfectly examined every word you said, but you have the right idea.  Just give some of the items ahead of time to the specified bins who have minimum requirements and remove that from the items still needing to be distributed.  You have an error or arithmetic mistake in your second expression though.  Recall that $(N-K) \color{red}{+ K} - 1$, there is still that $+K$ that you seem to have forgotten about there, giving $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$ for the number of ways to distribute such that every bin receives at least one item.

Comment: That is precisely the other manner in which people think of [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and matches "theorem 1" in the linked wiki article.  In your third expression, you have an $m$ in your expression but your description of what the expression represents has a $c$ instead.  Careful to use consistent variable names.

Comment: As for your final section... note the distinction between the phrases "*At least one bin needs to be non-empty*"  and "*At least bin1 has to be non-empty.*"  In neither of these do we need to multiply the expression by $K$.  There is no "*choosing the non-empty bin*" going on.  In the second, our choice was forced to be bin1.  In the first, it should be clear that so long as $N\neq 0$ there is going to be at least one bin who receives at least one item per the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @JMoravitz Doesn't "At least one bin needs to be non-empty" imply that the non-empty bin can be chosen? Which there are $K$ choices?

Comment: No.  Consider two bins and two items.  This should be small enough that you can list everything out.  You have the outcomes $(2,0),(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$.  Note that in all three of those, you have at least one nonempty bin.  What you counted was the number of ways of taking a big sign that says "Hey, this bin will be non-empty" and placing that sign in front of some bin and one of the items in the bin, and then distributing the rest of the items.  The outcomes you counted then were $(*2,0),(*1,1),(1,*1),(0,*2)$.  Note that you treated $(*1,1)$ differently than $(1,*1)$ (*where $*$ is the sign*)

Comment: Note that the opposite of "*At least one bin needs to be non-empty*" is "*All bins need to be empty*" which is impossible so long as you have at least one item to distribute.

Comment: With regards to "*At least one bin needs to have at least $m$ items in it*", for that I recommend approaching via [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) over the events "Bin1 has at least $m$ items in it", "Bin2 has at least $m$ items in it", etc...  In the case of $N=K=2$ and $m=1$, that was $2+2-1=3$, as expected.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hmm, yes it seems that formula leads to overcounting. So for the case where it's just "at least one bin needs to be non-empty" the formula is the same as "distribute $N$ items among $K$ beans" because of the pigeon hole principle? Because the 2 are actually equivalent as long as you have $N > 0$.

Comment: The problem can be easily solved with generating functions.